# How to disable the startup "Web Authentication for Google" application?

Tags: gnome, evolution, google

I've already allowed this application to access my Google account's data, however, this message keeps popping up every time I restart my computer.

> ***Account authentication[image]***

[image: After logging in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem, logged into Google, My Account, went to connected apps, manage apps, removed Gnome Evolution, logged out, restarted ubuntu, when the pop up appeared, clicked allow and it went away, this seems to have solved the problem.

The bug only appeared after I installed the latest updates for ubuntu 16.10

Comment: This is useful knowing that the bug only appears after installing the latest 16.10 updates. However, it does not answer the original question and therefore should be added as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: At first try your solution didn't work out for me. Now, after allowing and removing Gnome Evolution by the second time, apparently this problem is gone. Thank you.